# C++: recursive_directory_Iterator. two similar using,but in one of them throwing exeption

Tags: c++, filesystems

Code with throwing exeption: **terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::filesystem_error'
what():  filesystem error: cannot increment recursive directory iterator: Invalid argument

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::filesystem;


void explore(const directory_entry& directory,size_t& counter) {
  for(const auto& entry : recursive_directory_iterator{ directory.path() }) {
     cout<<"\nREC: "<<entry;
     counter++;
  }
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    if(argc) cout<<"";
    if(argc!=3){
        cerr<<"Wrong arguments. Usage app \"PATH\" \"three symbols extension\"\n";
        return -1;
    }
    recursive_directory_iterator di{argv[1]},end;
    size_t counter{};
    explore(directory_entry{argv[1]},counter);
    (counter)? cout<<"\nTotal files in "<<argv[1]<<"with extension *"<<argv[2]<<" is "<<counter<<"\n": cout<<"\nFiles with extension "<<argv[2]<<" not found\n";

    

}
```

Code with no exeption throwing:

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::filesystem;

struct Attributes {
  size_t size_bytes;
  size_t n_directories;
  size_t n_files;
};

void print_line(const Attributes& attributes, string_view path) {
  cout << setw(12) << attributes.size_bytes << setw(6) << attributes.n_files << setw(6) << attributes.n_directories
       << " " << path << "\n";
}

Attributes explore(const directory_entry& directory) {
  Attributes attributes{};
  for(const auto& entry : recursive_directory_iterator{ directory.path() }) {
     cout<<"\nREC: "<<entry;
  }
  return attributes;
}

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
  if(argc < 2) {
    cerr << "Usage: treedir PATH";
    return -1;
  }
  path sys_path{};
  std::string args{};
  if(argv[1][0]=='-'){
    args=argv[1];
    sys_path=argv[2];
  }
  else{
    sys_path=argv[1];
  }
  bool recursive{};
  for(auto& val:args){
    if(val=='R') recursive=1;
  }

  cout << "Size         Files  Dirs Name\n";
  cout << "------------ ----- ----- ------------\n";
  Attributes root_attributes{};
  for(const auto& entry : directory_iterator{ sys_path }) {
    try {
      if(entry.is_directory()) {
        if(recursive){
        const auto attributes = explore(entry);
        print_line(attributes, entry.path().string());
      }
        root_attributes.n_directories++;
      } else {
        root_attributes.n_files++;
        error_code ec;
        root_attributes.size_bytes += entry.file_size(ec);
        if(ec)
          cerr << "Error reading file size: " << entry.path().string() << endl;
      }
    } catch(const exception&) {
    }
  }
  print_line(root_attributes, sys_path.string());
}
```

In first case, when im start traverse from "C:" im getting exeption,but when i use D:\ traversing ok.In second case,traversing is ok for both C:\ and D:.

applying std::filesystem::directory_options by skip_permission_denied is no help.

Any ideas?

Comment: do not use `using namespace std` along with some names which MAY be a part of implementation or may exist both as global scope and as `std::`. You're inviting rather odd issues to happen.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Yeap,thanks! Is just remainder from my two days trying to figure out.  All attention to `explore()` functions =)

Comment: You can't tell that the code doesn't throw any exceptions when you catch them and deliberately ignore them.

Comment: @molbdnilo man,it doesn't matter in this case. Thanks! im agree, code looks like writed  it by my legs. but still..

Comment: still what? In the second code you to catch any exception that might be thrown and do nothing with it. Thats the main difference between the two versions and the answer to your question. The big difference is not that one throws the other not, but that one doesn catch the exception while the second does catch it

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number my bad. But second version is traversing further through directories,first stop at exception point

Comment: @c_thief Yes, that's how exceptions work. If you don't catch one, the program is terminated immediately. If you silently catch all of them, it will look like nothing happened.

Answer (score 2):

In second snippet you mask exceptions by `try {} catch` on a general type with no action taken.

Try (sorry) this version of function:

```
void explore(const directory_entry& directory, size_t& counter) {
    try {
        for (const auto& entry : recursive_directory_iterator{ directory.path() }) {
            cout << "\nREC: " << entry.path();
            counter++;
        }
    }
    catch (std::filesystem::filesystem_error e) {
        cerr << e.what();
    }
}
```

You'll see what's going on.
In my case

```
REC: "C:\\$Recycle.Bin"
REC: "C:\\$Recycle.Bin\\S-1-5-18"recursive_directory_iterator::operator++: Access is denied.
```

Program encountered a non-empty recycling bin and was denied the attempt to poke it. :P

For second case I used a function which would print a diagnostic message before propagating exception further up. Note, it might be not a good idea to use exceptions as a control flow. Where possible, it's prefereable to use  function return values.

```
Attributes explore(const directory_entry& directory, bool verbose) {
    Attributes attributes{};
    try {
        for (const auto& entry : recursive_directory_iterator{ directory.path(),std::filesystem::directory_options::skip_permission_denied }) {
            if (verbose)
                cout << "\nREC: " << entry.path();
        }
    }
    catch (std::filesystem::filesystem_error& e) {
        cerr << directory.path() << ":" << e.what();
        throw e;
    }
    return attributes;
}
```

and had liberty to add spam-control flag:

```
bool recursive{}, verbose{};
for (auto& val : args) {
    if (val == 'R') recursive = true;
    if (val == 'v') verbose = true;
}
```

To call explore():

```
            if (recursive) {
                const auto attributes = explore(entry, verbose);
```

Comment: thanks!  Please can you try it with directory_option as recursive_directory_iterator{ directory.path(),std::filesystem::directory_options::skip_permission_denied }, i can get in mind why i have exception like invalid argument. Think is crooked realization of Posix in Windows.

Comment: @c_thief More like Windows API got some edge cases. you might have files wth odd names in %temp% or recycler, or somewhere else. Or even a broken folder or link (kind of symbolic link from Linux).  I don't get that one, but I expirienced things like that. E.g. a folder that ends on.. space. Especially on Win10, there are a few bugs related to such names and access. It is unwise NOT to catch exceptions while working with filesystem.

Comment: @c_thief  you didn't forget to add `skip_permission_denied ` in both instances of that use, in `main()` too?

Comment: no,i had tried,exception still throwing with this option. Thank's bro, im screwed up with exception handling,in second case,is just handlind in loop, it happens when i read inattentively. But for now,i know more about exception handlind =) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Reducing your two versions to the essentials, you are comparing this:

```
// A
size_t N = 100;
for (size_t i=0; i<N; ++i) {
     might_throw();
}
```

with

```
// B
size_t N = 100;
for (size_t i=0; i<N; ++i) {
     try {
         might_throw();
     } catch(const exception& e) {
         // do nothing
     }
}
```

In the first, when `might_throw` throws an exception then the exception travels up in the call stack and because nowhere you catch the exception the program will terminate. When an exception is thrown in the first iterations, then other iterations will not be executed.

In the second, when `might_throw` throws an exception then the exception is caught by the `try-catch`. You don't do anything with the exception and then the next iteration is executed. When an exception is thrown in the first iteration, then the other iterations are still executed.

You can replace `//do nothing` with eg `std::cout << e.what() << "\n";` to produce some output in case of an exception. Most likely you will see the same exceptions being thrown in both variants of your code (except that the first will terminate after the first).

Comment: Thanks! That is it. Im screwed up with exception handlind,my bad.